# How to use Ajv with Typescript/Webpack/Babel environment?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ajv

I have a React application written in TS that needs to use a microservice through REST API. I want to use the JSON schema to validate the API response, so I will not need to do unsafe-casting to an existent type. I wrote the schema and managed everything to compile, however, Ajv fails to load at runtime with this error:

```
fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js?158e:21 ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at eval (core.js?f52c:29)
    at Module../node_modules/ajv/dist/core.js (vendors~application-dfdea6bdbb28cb54654a.chunk.js:60097)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~application-aa001ceb574a6f67800d.js:80)
    at eval (ajv.js?8fb6:34)
    at Object../node_modules/ajv/dist/ajv.js (vendors~application-dfdea6bdbb28cb54654a.chunk.js:59881)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~application-aa001ceb574a6f67800d.js:80)
    at eval (index.ts:6)
```

I understand that the problem is that 'ajv/dist/ajv' is a CommonJS file. But I have no idea how to make it work without affecting the build pipeline of the whole application.